# How to implement @JavascriptInterface for android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Currently, my code is not giving normal output. Why is this so?

Android:

```
@JavascriptInterface
fun call(obj:JSONObject?){
    Log.i("webview","$obj")
}
```

output on Logcat

> I: webview, null

js:

```
function callAndroid(obj) {
                    androidObj.call(obj);              
            }

callAndroid({
                    key_string: 'test'
                })
```

it is implemented add androidObj to webview ,that is successful

```
Android:
@JavascriptInterface
fun call(str:String?)

js:
androidObj.call('hello')
```

but parameter use JSONObject is failed

Comment: I put the problem you are having at the beginning, and I also formatted the output which you are having trouble with at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 steps to create JavaScript interface for Android WebView.

First, Create the Javascript interface:

```
@JavascriptInterface
fun call(obj:JSONObject?){
    Log.i("webview","$obj")
}
```

Second, Add Javascript interface to your WebView and enable Javascript:

```
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "androidObj")
```

Now call the function from your JS:

```
androidObj.call(obj)
```

Check if you have missed any of the above steps.

Comment: Sorry, I skipped a few steps, but I've implemented them, If use android:{fun call(obj:String?)} and js:{androidObj.call('hello')} that is successful,But use JSONObject as the 'call' argument, it is failed

Comment: Yes, Because it is not able to convert the passed object to Kotlin/Java JSON object. Pass the object as a string and then parse it in the android. like `val jsonObject = JSONObject(argument)`.

Comment: thx! I looked it up in the official documents, but no clear answer was found